# Java regex to remove styles from HTML tags for Jasper text field

Tags: java, regex

As stated in the title - I am looking for safest Java regex to remove styles from HTML tags intended for Jasper text field marked as HTML, but not touching any content and tags consistency. For example, for the following input received from front-end:

```html
<p>This text contains <sub style="background-color:powderblue;">subscript</sub> text.</p>
```

Sorry for not escaped quotes. I found this code works fine:

```java
String output = input.replaceAll("style=\"[^>]*\"","");
```

then output should be:

```html
 <p>This text contains <sub>subscript</sub> text.</p>
```

Comment: Don't use regex for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, a regex isn't something to use if you want to remove something. A regex is purely a *check* if something matches a certain set of characters.

But apart from that, this code using `replaceAll` should do the trick

```java
String output = input.replaceAll(
        "(<[^>]+?)\\s+style\\s*=\\s*['\"][^'\"]*['\"](.*?>)", "$1$2");
```

Comment: @AndrzejWięcławski Happy it helped. Can you also accept the answer, so other devs who might run into the same problem, know there's a fix for it?

Comment: After tests it seems justified to remove <ol> and <ul> tags. There are ridiculous blank line before enumerating starts in jasper text field... Can you find any solution?

Comment: As this is another functionality, I'd recommend to just create a secondary `replaceAll`, which just replaces any `<ol>` & `<ul>` tags